# Why did all my tables lost borders (Word 2007)?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

My MS Word 2007 document had too many rogue "headings" in the automatic table of contents. I switched to the outline view, selected all the text and demoted it to "body text", that solved this issue.

However, now I've noticed that about a 100 little tables I had created in the document have all lost their borders (the borders became transparent). Could this be related to my "bulk demotion" of the text to "body text", and is there a way to quickly restore standard visible borders in all tables?

There is no way to CTRL-Z this, because I've edited the text quite a lot after that demotion: fixed spelling, formatted headings, changed words, etc.

This is a translated text, and the tables are under the numerous charts: they contain translations of the terms used in the charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all those tables have a specific style (and they should), you can just edit that style.

If not, you'll have to do them one by one, but just define a style on the first one, and apply it to each one.

Comment: Where can I edit the style? I can't find any menu for table styles.. I found "Table Tools >> Design" but it has no button for determining a style.

Comment: Is there a way to select all the borderless tables in a document and then bulk-apply a style to them at once? I feel a fool going through the already-created tables by hand. At some moment I could inadvertently make them invisible again. D'oh.